# Keep rows in dataframe where value in each list is in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following.

```
import pandas as pd

# intialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Lists':["4,67,3,4,53,32", "7,3,44,2,5,6,9", "8,9,23", "9,36,21,32"]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to keep the rows where each list 'Lists' has any value in the pre-defined list [1,2,3,4,5]
What would be the most efficient and rapid way of doing it.
I'd like to avoid a for loop, and asking your proficiency in pandas df to ask you what's the best way to achieve this.

In the example above, this would keep only the rows for 'Tom' and 'nick'.

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you get this dataframe? What is the origin? You won't be able to do it without a for loop, you need one, implicit or explicit.

Comment: What did you try which failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
values = set(str(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # note the set
idx = df['Lists'].str.split(',').map(lambda x: len(values.intersection(x)) > 0)
df.loc[idx, 'Name']


0     Tom
1    nick
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

First convert the values to a set for faster membership tests (if you have many values), then filter rows where 'Lists' intersects the values.

Comment: my bad, i've just edited my question. It's not lists but strings. Thank you for your answer but can you please amend it to make it work?

Comment: Why don't you just convert it to list first? Like `df['Lists'].str.split(',')`